# Method using Func<T,TResult> as parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, functional-programming

I need some help on simplifying my method

I have this method

```
public double ComputeBasicAmount(double basicLimit, double eligibleAmt)
{
  return basicLimit * eligibleAmt;
}
```

sample usage:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(100, 1000);
double basicAmt = ComputeBasicAmount(foo.BasicLimit, foo.EligibleAmt)
```

The problem here is I want the eligibleAmt to be dynamic **because sometimes
it's not really only the eligbleAmt what I'm passing to the method**.. like this

```
Foo foo = new Foo(100, 1000);
double basicAmt = ComputeBasicAmount(foo.BasicLimit, foo.EligibleAmt/foo.RoomRate)
```

My solution is use the **Func** delegate as a parameter but i don't know how to use it properly

i want something functional like this

```
public double ComputeBasicAmount<T>(double basicLimit, Func<T, double> multiplier)
{

 return basicLimt * multiplier;
}

double basicAmt = ComputeBasicAmount<Foo>(foo.BasicLimit, x => x.EligibleAmt/x.RoomRate)
```

can someone help me. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the multiplier depends on the item then *either* you'll need to pass the item as well, *or* you'll need to return a `Func<T, double>`:

```
public double ComputeBasicAmount<T>(double basicLimit,
                                    Func<T, double> multiplier,
                                    T item)
{    
    return basicLimt * multiplier(item);
}
...

double basicAmt = ComputeBasicAmount<Foo>(
                        foo.BasicLimit,
                        x => x.EligibleAmt / x.RoomRate,
                        foo)
```

or

```
public Func<T, double> ComputeBasicAmount<T>(double basicLimit,
                                             Func<T, double> multiplier)
{    
    return item => basicLimt * multiplier(item);
}
...
var basicAmtFunc = ComputeBasicAmount<Foo>(
                        foo.BasicLimit,
                        x => x.EligibleAmt / x.RoomRate);

var basicAmt = basicAmntFunc(foo);
```

If neither of those is what you were looking for, please explain where you want the *actual* value of `T` to be provided so that you can work out the multiplier.

The first is very similar to just having a `Func<double>` to compute the multiplier, of course... which in turn is pretty much like *calling* that `Func<double>` when computing the arguments, to get back to your original version which just takes two doubles.

Comment: I can use this if I need the actual value of T, but for this scenario I'm only evaluating double value property of different objects . Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

You can declare it simply as a `Func<double>` (that way you are not making the method dependent on the `Foo` type), and pass any method taking no parameters and returning a double as argument:

```
public static double ComputeBasicAmount(double basicLimit, Func<double> multiplier)
{
    return basicLimit * multiplier();
}
```

Some example calls:

```
class Foo
{
    public double One;
    public double Two;
}


Foo f = new Foo();
double result = ComputeBasicAmount(f.One, () => f.Two);
```

You can also have some other method returning a `double`

```
public static double GetDoubleValue()
{
    return 4.2;
}
```

...and pass that as argument:

```
double result = ComputeBasicAmount(42,GetDoubleValue);
```

Comment: can you do a Generic version of this, because its not FOO object what im going to pass. thanks

Comment: oh man, I guess I don't have to use Generics here because I do not have to pass the Type... thanks man...

Comment: @user444024: exactly. The method is already as generic as it gets, given that we always want to operate on `double` values.

Answer (score 0):

You'd declare your method something like this, so the multiplier is a delegate that takes a Foo object and returns a double:

```
double ComputeBasicAmount(
   double basicLimit, Foo foo, Func<Foo, double> multiplier)
```

Then call it like this, passing a lambda into the multiplier:

```
double basicAmt = ComputeBasicAmount(
   foo.BasicLimit, foo, x => x.EligibleAmt / x.RoomRate);
```

Comment: This isn't correct as a `Foo` instance is not being passed in so there's nothing for the `ComputeBasicAmount` to call the `Func` with.

Comment: thanks but my method is the same as yours the difference is mine is Generic

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Func<double>` since you only use the double result

```
public double ComputeBasicAmount(double basicLimit, Func<double> multiplier)
{    
    return basicLimt * multiplier();
}
```

Then call it like this

```
double basicAmt = ComputeBasicAmount<Foo>(foo.BasicLimit, x => x.EligibleAmt/x.RoomRate)
```

But then you could have a regular double parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, With your help I was able to make my existing code much more readable and functional...

```
    class RNB
    {
        public RNB(double roomRate, double roomDays)
        {
            RoomRate = roomRate;
            RoomDays = roomDays;
        }

        public double RoomRate { get; set; }
        public double RoomDays { get; set; }
        public const double BasicLimit = 100;
    }

    class HMS
    {
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public const double BasicLimit = 200;
    }

    public static double ComputeBasicAmount(double basicLimit, Func<double> multiplier)
    {
        return basicLimit * multiplier();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RNB rnb = new RNB(100, 2);
        double result = ComputeBasicAmount(RNB.BasicLimit, () => rnb.RoomDays * rnb.RoomRate);
        Console.WriteLine("RNB Basic Amt: " + result.ToString());

        HMS hms = new HMS() { Amount = 1000 };
        result = ComputeBasicAmount(HMS.BasicLimit, () => hms.Amount);
        Console.WriteLine("HMS Basic Amt: " + result.ToString());

        Console.Read();
    }
```

But I have another problem here.. I Want to eliminate the passing of the BasicLimit because i think it looks redundant here. Is it possible to put the  BasicLimit inside the ComputeBasicAmount method

Something like this..

```
 public static double ComputeBasicAmount<T>(Func<T, double> multiplier, T obj)
  {

      return obj.BasicLimit * multiplier();
  }
```

But I have to put this question in another thread because I think its another topic...
See you guys there... thanks...